# Making parent adjust to size of child widget

Tags: flutter, layout, widget

I am using a ListView Builder, and that has to be wrapped inside a Container. If i don't give a height parameter then i get `Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.` Now, because of this if i only have 1 item in the list, any content comes after the container, which wastes a lot of screen real estate and doesn't look aesthetically pleasing.

How can i make the parent widget i.e `Container()` to adjust to the size of child widget `ListView.builder()` ?

[image: this is the image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this **shrinkWrap: true** to your ListView and Remove Height from **container**.

snippet code:

```
return Container(
        child: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return listItem(itemArray[index]),
        },
        itemCount: itemArray.length,
        shrinkWrap: true),
      );
```